# Finding all functions with a radial gradient field

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm looking for all functions $f=f(x,y,z)$ whose gradient takes the form
$$\nabla f(x,y,z)=\lambda(x,y,z)(x \mathbf{i}+y \mathbf{j}+z \mathbf{k}).$$
Using the identity $\nabla \times \nabla f=\mathbf{0}$, I got the system of PDEs
$$\frac{\lambda_x}{x}=\frac{\lambda_y}{y}=\frac{\lambda_z}{z}. $$
I know that functions of the form $$\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2) $$ are all solutions, but are all solutions of the PDEs of this form?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how to conclude using this method. I would rather use polar coordinates $r, \theta, \phi$. The requirement that $\nabla f$ be radial is equivalent to the requirement that $\partial_\theta f=\partial_\phi f=0$, so $f=f(r)$.